# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

[image: Pat Ludwig] [image: AceCallhoon]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: What's your question? (j/k) Congrads to @Bryant, @C. Ross and @mxyzplk!

Comment: *sniff* Our little SE site is growing up so fast. Before we know it, it'll be off to college.

Comment: College! Ah, those days when I had five nights a week free for gaming.

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence and am off to crush peoples' hopes and dreams even as we speak.

Comment: Well, *someone* needs to play the bad cop if that trope is going to work.

Comment: Ross has a picture now! Beardy!

Comment: I look forward to working with y'all to build a *great site*!

Answer (score 2):

Bryant is clearly insane (see Rep), so he'd obviously be best; nobody would dare upset him. ;>

Answer (score 2):

And R. S. Conley, who just got the mod tag! Excellent. Hey, R.S., if you did the odd tag wiki I'm really sorry. :(

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. As for the wiki entry don't sweat about it. I fixed it. Just how these things go.

Comment: @RS Conley Welcome, we look forward to having you on the team!