# When and how do we elect moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, process

I know we have moderators *pro tempore*. I saw [in that thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) Robert Cartaino on Sept. 7, 2010 announced that we'd have our elections "in several weeks." Is that based on the Beta ending? Will the nomination and election process be the same as we did for pro tems?

When exactly do we elect "real" ones? Cuz I want to put my name in the hat and I assume it's too late to apply for a Pro Tem position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are building out community moderator election support as a standard feature of all Stack Exchange sites.

As soon as the site launches from beta, we'll hold nominations (which will be announced on the main site). After a reasonable nomination period (TBD), the elections will begin. The election process (which will also be announced on the main site) will be an external piece of software where users will select their choices. I have not seen the software, but I imagine it will work very similarly as it did in the 2010 Stack Oveflow elections:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/

Comment: Just revisiting this thread and noting that, soon after we launch from beta, we'll be able to elect moderators.