# 2012 Community Moderator Election - Reelection Too?

Tags: discussion, election

I got a question on my nomination saying "but aren't you a mod already?"  I guess I figured this was for reelection of the previous mods as well, but after reviewing the posts it's unclear.  Should me, CRoss, etc. be nominating ourselves to stand as mods, or is this for additional mods beyond us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should. Refer back to the emails we sent you when you were appointed (yeah, I know, so much dust) or [the Pro Tempore program blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections after the Beta period.

You and [the other pro tempore moderators](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) can (AND SHOULD!) nominate yourself for re-election. Once the election is over, all non-elected pro-tems will no longer be moderators.

Either way, thanks for *all* of your work in getting the site to this point!

Answer (score 3):

*Elected* mods stay seated and don't have to be reelected, you only have to "renominate" is when you're a Pro Temp mod entering in the first Election.

Since you're a pro temp (like all other mods this round) if you want to run, you'll have to nominate yourself and be elected. Pro temps are *temporary* mods, [elected mods are for life](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms)*.

<sub>*unless they step down, outstanding circumstances ect</sub>