# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Well, Role-Playing Games' very first [moderator election](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to an end. Our winners are:

[image: Brian Ballsun-Stanton] [image: mxyzplk] [image: C. Ross]

Please give them a warm welcome, and hearty thanks and congratulations for volunteering!

Also, a sincere thank you to the rest of our [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), who (along with mxyzplk and C. Ross) helped shepherd the site through its beta:

[image: RS Conley]
[image: Pat Ludwig]
[image: AceCalhoon]

Comment: I for one welcome our new (robot?) overlords.

Comment: Woo! I'm happy with all those winners! Now, to go cause some trouble so you can earn your keep.... :)

Answer (score 15):

Thanks all!  My first action as robot overlord will be to crush your hopes and dreams.

Comment: situation normal, then?

Comment: Until we trick him into typing his name backwards!

Comment: I hope and dream for the crushing of my hopes and dreams.

Comment: ...Does not... Compute!?

Comment: What is the value of Pi?

Comment: Pis is evil, use [tau instead](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto) ...

Comment: Let's play tic-tac-toe. Number of players: zero.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats to all indeed, and thanks to the pro tempore team. :)