# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Role-Playing Games' [third moderator election](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: doppelgreener] [image: nitsua60]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6222615786029056/0).

Comment: Congratulations! And thank you, everyone who ran this time.

Comment: Congratulations and best of luck in your new positions! :)

Comment: Congratulations, guys ^^

Comment: Both amazing people who deserve it! I've had nothing but positive and enlightening interactions with both of them!  ^_^

Comment: Congrats, guys!

Comment: Congratulations nitsua60.

Comment: And now we have our very own masqued-marauder and sheep-person (sheeple?!) diamond carriers. Congrats to them, and all of RPG.SE: Forward, to glory!

Comment: Happy moderating.

Comment: Congratulations Nitsua and Doppelgreener for your victory in the election.

Answer (score 12):

Congrats to @dopplegreener and @nitsua60, and thanks to all the candidates, voters, and our Community Moderator team for participating in the election in their various ways.

Comment: Dare I ask why you are persecuting all of the lesser vote-getters?

Comment: Just living up to [my own campaign promises](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1563/140).

Answer (score 10):

#### Be Careful of What You Wish For, As You Will Surely Get It! ( 8^D )

Grats to you both!  I daresay that our two sitting mods will be tickled pink to have the both of you on side.  Great choices by those who voted.

Advice?  Uh, be yourself.  That's what got you voted in.

#### Post Mortem

The primaries indicated to me that it would be a three-horse race with you two and Josh.  [The actual results surprise me somewhat](https://www.opavote.com/results/6222615786029056), since I took a look at the primaries and noted that I accrued a good number of down votes to offset up votes.  I figured Joshua would pull ahead as the elimination rounds proceeded.
Like at the soon-to-be-run Kentucky Derby, nits and dopp hit the clubhouse turn and left the rest of the field in the dust (or mud).

Good thing I didn't bet (uh, all of) the rent money on that prediction. (Turns head and calls across the room: *Yes, Honey, I'm cooking red beans and rice for dinner, why do you ask?*)

*Interesting stat*: 3,005 voters were eligible, 906 visited the site during the election, 769 visited the election page, and 366 voted. No analysis of those numbers will be provided.

#### Enough Analysis, It's Time To Party Like It's 2017!

Goodonya both, looking forward to the diamonds adorning your handles on site.

I shall now retire to the bar with Joshua, and work on my concession speech.  I think it starts with "Hey, Josh, we wuz robbed!" or something like that. 8^D

*Wait, is this mic on?*

---

Primary Upvote/Downvote pairs without names, per @darkwanderer's point.

+61/-16; +226/-4; +288/-7; +134/-10; +33/-26; +18/-33; +83/-23; +17/-79; +12/-52; +147/-16; +25/-33

Comment: Remember that primaries allow downvotes while main elections don't.  An extremely divisive candidate could have ended up with +183/-182 for a total primary score of '1' and, were they the first choice for those 183 people, nonetheless swept the main election handily. This largely accounts for your success over Josh; you got many strong positive upvotes and strong negative downvotes while Josh got enough upvotes to be solidly ahead in the primary score, but not so much in the actual election.  Or this is my guessing anyways; the primary results seem not to be available anymore.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Found the numbers.

Comment: Well maybe that didn't actually come up then XD;  I'm not really sure how to read those numbers, but it looks to me like doppelgreener and nitsua60 were *solidly* ahead the whole time, and I assume the race for third we see there is you and josh.

Comment: Yeah, with all of the negative votes that some of the candidates got, I wasn't sure how much would move during the elimination rounds, but since you mention that there is no down voting in the final election, that "negative sentiments" were not as significant as I suspected they'd be.  Food for thought, or better, yet, Beer for Thought!

Comment: I'm surprised 3 other people thought I was worthy of a vote :)  And that I didn't come in dead last.

Comment: @doppelgreener wrong candidate :)

Comment: @Marshall oh nooooo.... [hides evidence]

Comment: @doppelgreener one day and the corruption has gotten to  you....tsk tsk

Comment: @MarshallTigerus "Power tends to corrupt, and absolute power corrupts absolutely. Great men are almost always bad men, even when they exercise influence and not authority: still more when you superadd the tendency or the certainty of corruption by authority. There is no worse heresy than that the office sanctifies the holder of it."  -- Lord Acton ;-)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast "Lob thy Holy Hand Grenade at thine foe, and he, being naughty in my sight, shall snuff it." - God

Answer (score 3):

Nice.  Congrats to you both.  Especially for @nitsua60, who gave me encouragement early on!